# How do I know if my private net is using Byzantium?

Tags: go-ethereum

Is there a flag that is showing that Byzantium is actually enabled in my private network?

This is the only thing I have found in my log at `geth` startup:

```
INFO [10-26|01:10:40] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: 1111 Homestead: <nil> DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: false EIP150: <nil> EIP155: <nil> EIP158: <nil> Byzantium: <nil> Engine: unknown}"
```

But I am not sure if this data is meaningful.

Is there somthing like

```
>eth.bizantiumActive()
1
```

???

Comment: Did you find any solution? thanks in advance

Comment: @sharif2008, apparently Byzantium introduced new opcodes (not sure which ones but you can look at the sources and find out there), so you can create a `Call()` which will use CREATE , and the code in this CREATE has to include this new opcode. If the EVM fails, then it is not Byzantium. Kind of difficult stuff, but non-intrusive , i.e. you don't have to create transactions to find it out.

Answer (score 5):

In your genesis config file, you should see config field, then set ByzantiumBlock to 0, like this [image]

and make sure you geth version is greater than 1.7.0, you can send a simple transaction to the private network, and getTransactionReceipt, if you see status field not root field in the receipt, then Byzantium fork is live.

Comment: but my genesis file has been already created, and now I can not change it because it has accumulated some proof of work

Comment: I have tried to set Byzantium block  to some number of few blocks in the future, when it is mined, nothing happens, I don't get Byzantium version. The returned value from getTransactionReceipt() is the whole transaction record. Do you have an example of how it looks on the console when you query the transaction receipt?

Comment: I have been debugging, and the problem is , even if I edit params/config.go and set Byzantium block to 0 or whatever, `geth` wont switch to Byzantium, it will only switch if you have it in the genesis, but I don't. So I think I will be hardcoding IsByzantium() function to return `true` , that's the only way I can think of.

Comment: I have hardcoded the function to true and it works, status=0x01 is now returned. But I don't know if this will create some problems with my blockchain. Apparently not, but you never know.

Answer (score 2):

The trick that worked for me was to create a new node with an updated genesis (use geth v1.7.2). And add the new node as a peer to the old node (old node runs geth v1.6.7). They should be able to sync without problems.

You have to make sure both clients have generated the same block 0 from the genesis file. If the blocks are different the synchronization will not start and you will not be able to proceed.

After the new node is synchonized, you can shutdown the old node and start working in the new blockchain exclusively. You should mine some blocks until the byzantinumBlock is reached, and from there byzantinum features should be active in your private testnet.

Comment: I just went through this with geth v1.8.27 and a private net.  You can just straight up add a `byzantiumBlock` to the genesis config and bring your nodes back up.  Just make sure the block number is in the future.  The fork will happen cleanly.