# Where is my transaction status?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions

I was told that I can get the Status from a transaction recript. But why I can't find it in the response?

The command below is executed inside GETH console. And the output is followed.

```
> web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt("0x2f32a07ebec4500fb15fe2cd73c76c05e508953631ad286ec8c4714942fbfbe5")
{
  blockHash: "0xd41e9d28f7af302ce98026d612e2e904a56cf89b72dc995d7c607cbb65abd207",
  blockNumber: 236,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 43035,
  from: "0xc8caa71c16299b40b8579742a27ee53162886040",
  gasUsed: 43035,
  logs: [{
      address: "0xbd4c00713e706c6f350f8e8e3595a1bf0289c118",
      blockHash: "0xd41e9d28f7af302ce98026d612e2e904a56cf89b72dc995d7c607cbb65abd207",
      blockNumber: 236,
      data: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000",
      logIndex: 0,
      removed: false,
      topics: ["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef", "0x000000000000000000000000c8caa71c16299b40b8579742a27ee53162886040", "0x00000000000000000000000060fdf758ed3549d550a52f2044b43aadf782aa4e"],
      transactionHash: "0x2f32a07ebec4500fb15fe2cd73c76c05e508953631ad286ec8c4714942fbfbe5",
      transactionIndex: 0
  }],
  logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000410000000000000000000000000000000000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000800000000000000000000000000000404000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000",
  root: "0x50881a2fec4beaf7998751d9463607e048f5525a596d761c7a6563abd745bb6d",
  to: "0xbd4c00713e706c6f350f8e8e3595a1bf0289c118",
  transactionHash: "0x2f32a07ebec4500fb15fe2cd73c76c05e508953631ad286ec8c4714942fbfbe5",
  transactionIndex: 0
}
```

Comment: You need to enable the byzantinum fork with `byzantinumBlock` option in the config section of your genesis file like this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/29264 .

Comment: yep, it's because Byzantium is not enabled