# Deploying and calling a contract works only with Ganache (not with Geth)

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-invocation

I deployed a HelloWorld contract using web3j and it worked awesome with Ganache. I was able to call my only function from the contract and it returns the desired result all the time.

When I deploy the contract to a private node created with geth, the transaction appears in pendingTransactions list and it returns the address of the deployed contract shortly after starting mining, but I cannot call the funciton. It always returns 0x (tested with both geth console and web3j). As you can see it is there.
[image]
 After starting the miner you can observe that it is successfully deployed:
[image]

This is the code that deploys the contract (it works with Ganache):
[image]

The problem is that every time when I want to call a function it returns 0x just like the contract is not there. I checked and geth manages to find the specific contract:
[image]

EDIT:

I used 3 methods to call the contract: Java code using web3j, Geth console and Remix ide.

1) As you can see the contract is deployed(it appeared at pending transactions and was added to the blockchain after I started the miner. The idea is that the result of the method is still empty string not "helloWorld")[image]

2) From Geth console it fails to cast the value to BigNumber. I read somewhere that this might be because the node is not synchronized and it doesn't know what value to return, so it returns empty value. 
[image]

3) From Java using Web3j
[image]

It throws an exceptions because the value returned is 0x and it fails to cast it:

[image]

Genesis.json

```
{


"config": {
    "chainId": 3792,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0
  },
  "difficulty": "2000",
  "gasLimit": "3141592000000",
  "alloc": {
    "ca56bdff4ab30b96b4f618e718b88c7a1721ecc3": {
      "balance": "300000000000000000000"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you make the contract call?

Comment: @Ismael I edited the original question in order to include the methods used to call the functions inside the contract. Thank you!

Comment: I tried your code with geth 1.8.17 and its "dev" chain, and your code works as expected from remix. Are you testing against a private testnet or a public one, ie ropsten, rinkeby, etc. In case you use a private testnet what's is your genesis file like? Are byzantinum opcodes enabled?

Comment: I am testing it against a private network (I created a node using geth and my custom genesis.json) but I didn't specify anything related to the byzantinum opcodes. I attached my genesis json to the question.

Comment: That might be it. In the byzantinum fork there were a new opcodes introduced RETURNDATASIZE and RETURNDATACOPY https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-211.

Comment: How can I enable them? Are there some specific key/values for genesis.json?

Comment: See this answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/29264, you have to add "byzantinumBlock" value in the "config" section of the genesis file.

Comment: It didn't work :( . For now I will stick with 1.5.9 which seems to work for local nodes.

Comment: When you modify the genesis file you have to restart your blockchain.

Comment: I deleted the previous node and initialised a new one (geth --datadir "node" init genesis.json) and still I was not able to retrieve the correct value (still empty value). Also I would like to specify that the Byzantium property was 0 in the logs that appear when I start the node (it means that it was successfully initialised from the genesis.json) and the status property is available for a receipt so it works with Byzantium.

Comment: Anyway thank you very much for your time and help!

Comment: I used puppeth to create my chain it is something like this https://gist.github.com/eternnoir/06d38345db67d316acda94e25b4737ca and it works without issues.

Comment: Sorry, but I have been very busy during these last days and couldn't try again. Hopefully I will manage to test this configuration tomorrow. Anyway I will let you know the result :) .

Comment: Good news! I managed to obtain the desired functionality with this configuration but with an older version of the compiler. I was trying to use the 0.5.6 version of solc but it appears that there might be some problem, so I tried with 0.4.19 and it works. Thank you very much! You are awesome!

Comment: Okay, so I think that I discovered the source of the problem. I was using the version 0.5.6 of solc with geth 1.8.22(stable). Geth was released in February and I think that it is not compatible with the new versions of solc, considering that I am capable to deploy a contract that was compiled with 0.5.4 that was released befero 1.8.22

Answer (score 1):

TLDR, but here is a fundamental difference between Ganache and Geth:

When Ganache starts, it automatically unlocks the accounts specified in the command-line.

For example:

```
ganache-cli
    --port=8545
    --gasPrice=20000000000
    --gasLimit=8000000
    --account=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001,1000000
    --account=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002,1000000
```

Will unlock the accounts with private keys `0x0...1` and `0x0...2` (2 accounts).

The default (if you don't specify anything) is `0x0...1` thru `0x0...a` (10 accounts).

Geth doesn't do that, so you must unlock the accounts yourself prior to running any of your Truffle tests, by sending to Geth an "unlock account" command for each one of the accounts used in these tests.

Alternatively, you can sign each transaction with your private key before sending it to your Geth node. Other than for testing, this approach is actually the recommended one, because if somebody hacks your node then they can obtain your account credentials.

Comment: I unlocked the account but the result is the same. https://imgur.com/a/pNSi44a