# Empty value (0x) returned from contract web3j

Tags: go-ethereum, dapps, web3j

I'm trying to deploy a very simple contract on Windows 10, using **Web3j 4.2.0**. I've created an account using Mist. I've set up one local ethereum node (using **geth**) on my machine and I'm able to deploy and interact with contracts using eg. Mist. 
But when I'm trying to do the same from Java code all the time I'm getting

```
org.web3j.tx.exceptions.ContractCallException: Empty value (0x) returned from contract

at org.web3j.tx.Contract.executeCallSingleValueReturn(Contract.java:250)
at org.web3j.tx.Contract.lambda$executeRemoteCallSingleValueReturn$1(Contract.java:317)
at org.web3j.protocol.core.RemoteCall.send(RemoteCall.java:30)
```

Here is my solidity contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.5;

contract SampleContract{
uint256 sampleVariable = 0;

    function setSample(uint256 x) public{
        sampleVariable = x;
    }
    function getSample() public view returns(uint256){
        return sampleVariable;
    }
}
```

I created a java wrapper class using solidity compiler and web3j CLI 4.2.0:

```
/**
 * <p>Auto generated code.
 * <p><strong>Do not modify!</strong>
 * <p>Please use the <a href="https://docs.web3j.io/command_line.html">web3j command line tools</a>,
 * or the org.web3j.codegen.SolidityFunctionWrapperGenerator in the 
 * <a href="https://github.com/web3j/web3j/tree/master/codegen">codegen module</a> to update.
 *
 * <p>Generated with web3j version 4.2.0.
 */
public class SampleContract extends Contract {
    private static final String BINARY = "60806040526000805534801561001457600080fd5b5060a2806100236000396000f3fe6080604052348015600f57600080fd5b506004361060325760003560e01c806331c8039b146037578063e221818b14604f575b600080fd5b603d606b565b60408051918252519081900360200190f35b606960048036036020811015606357600080fd5b50356071565b005b60005490565b60005556fea165627a7a72305820de9e3ced16dc30cb74a4215c04b4b6f5f61df43a4bc0c38fbbd23e798b6b805d0029";

    public static final String FUNC_GETSAMPLE = "getSample";

    public static final String FUNC_SETSAMPLE = "setSample";

    @Deprecated
    protected SampleContract(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, Credentials credentials, BigInteger gasPrice, BigInteger gasLimit) {
        super(BINARY, contractAddress, web3j, credentials, gasPrice, gasLimit);
    }

    protected SampleContract(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, Credentials credentials, ContractGasProvider contractGasProvider) {
        super(BINARY, contractAddress, web3j, credentials, contractGasProvider);
    }

    @Deprecated
    protected SampleContract(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, TransactionManager transactionManager, BigInteger gasPrice, BigInteger gasLimit) {
        super(BINARY, contractAddress, web3j, transactionManager, gasPrice, gasLimit);
    }

    protected SampleContract(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, TransactionManager transactionManager, ContractGasProvider contractGasProvider) {
        super(BINARY, contractAddress, web3j, transactionManager, contractGasProvider);
    }

    public RemoteCall<BigInteger> getSample() {
        final Function function = new Function(FUNC_GETSAMPLE, 
                Arrays.<Type>asList(), 
                Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<Uint256>() {}));
        return executeRemoteCallSingleValueReturn(function, BigInteger.class);
    }

    public RemoteCall<TransactionReceipt> setSample(BigInteger x) {
        final Function function = new Function(
                FUNC_SETSAMPLE, 
                Arrays.<Type>asList(new Uint256(x)),
                Collections.<TypeReference<?>>emptyList());
        return executeRemoteCallTransaction(function);
    }

    @Deprecated
    public static SampleContract load(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, Credentials credentials, BigInteger gasPrice, BigInteger gasLimit) {
        return new SampleContract(contractAddress, web3j, credentials, gasPrice, gasLimit);
    }

    @Deprecated
    public static SampleContract load(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, TransactionManager transactionManager, BigInteger gasPrice, BigInteger gasLimit) {
        return new SampleContract(contractAddress, web3j, transactionManager, gasPrice, gasLimit);
    }

    public static SampleContract load(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, Credentials credentials, ContractGasProvider contractGasProvider) {
        return new SampleContract(contractAddress, web3j, credentials, contractGasProvider);
    }

    public static SampleContract load(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, TransactionManager transactionManager, ContractGasProvider contractGasProvider) {
        return new SampleContract(contractAddress, web3j, transactionManager, contractGasProvider);
    }

    public static RemoteCall<SampleContract> deploy(Web3j web3j, Credentials credentials, ContractGasProvider contractGasProvider) {
        return deployRemoteCall(SampleContract.class, web3j, credentials, contractGasProvider, BINARY, "");
    }

    @Deprecated
    public static RemoteCall<SampleContract> deploy(Web3j web3j, Credentials credentials, BigInteger gasPrice, BigInteger gasLimit) {
        return deployRemoteCall(SampleContract.class, web3j, credentials, gasPrice, gasLimit, BINARY, "");
    }

    public static RemoteCall<SampleContract> deploy(Web3j web3j, TransactionManager transactionManager, ContractGasProvider contractGasProvider) {
        return deployRemoteCall(SampleContract.class, web3j, transactionManager, contractGasProvider, BINARY, "");
    }

    @Deprecated
    public static RemoteCall<SampleContract> deploy(Web3j web3j, TransactionManager transactionManager, BigInteger gasPrice, BigInteger gasLimit) {
        return deployRemoteCall(SampleContract.class, web3j, transactionManager, gasPrice, gasLimit, BINARY, "");
    }
}
```

Here is the java code of contract creation:

```
Credentials credentials = WalletUtils.loadCredentials(password,
        keystorePath);

SampleContract sampleContract= SampleContract.deploy(web3j, credentials, new DefaultGasProvider()).send();

LOGGER.info("Contract deployed under address: " + sampleContract.getContractAddress());

LOGGER.info("Is contract valid : " + sampleContract.isValid());

BigInteger sampleNumber = sampleContract.getSample().send();
```

I'm able to deploy contract, get its address, also check is this contract valid returns true. But when I try to read from it (the last line of code) it always throws org.web3j.tx.exceptions.ContractCallException.
Do you have any idea what's the reason of this? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

use the load(...) method from SampleContract Wrapper and then call getSample()

I can't test it now but it should look something like this

```
// your code for deploy and wait until it deployed
SampleContract myContract = SampleContract.load(<your-contract-address>, web3j, credentails, ......etc);
BigInteger sNumber = myContract.getSample().send();   
//or BigInteger sNumber = myContract.getSample().sendAsync().get();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. The result is the same..

Comment: same Exception?, could you try your code with Ganache instead of geth?

Comment: yes, my code is working with Ganache some default workspace. Thanks! Do you know what could be the problem with geth?

Comment: ok I found the solution after your tip, [this post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/68755/deploying-and-calling-a-contract-works-only-with-ganache-not-with-geth) helped also in my case (problem with wrong version of solc compiler).